# Referencing Class Library Project in .Net Core with FrameWork Project using System.Web.Mvc and .Net Core using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to reference class library project which is made in .Net framework with all my ViewModels having SelectListItems which uses System.Web.Mvc but my Project in which I want to reference is build using .Net Core
When I use SelectListItems of .Net Framework in .Net Core it gives error as .Net Core uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering for SelectListItems.

I don't want to copy all my ViewModels and use the same framework project where my ViewModels resides. Any solution for this?

Solution structure
Main project (ASP.NET MVC 4.8)
ViewModel Class library project  (ASP.NET MVC 4.8)
BusinessModel Class library project for defining business logics and helpers (ASP.NET MVC 4.8)
DataModel class library project for data model (ASP.NET MVC 4.8)
Customer Portal project is in (ASP.NET CORE 3.1)
we want to reference .NET Framework class library project in Customer portal project coded in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a .Net framework library from .Net Core or higher.  You can convert your .Net framework libraries to .Net Standard and then they could be use by either .Net Core or higher or .Net Framework.